Solve problem path of resistance stochastically stable equilibria
I'm working on Stochastically stable equilibria bout Evolutionary Game theory. In the famous paper by Peyton Young there is an example of a matrix 3x3 with the solution of the paths less resistance. I tried a lot to find the same but I am not able. SO someone is able? I put the matrix here and also the reference of the paper called The Evolution of Convention 1993 Young.
 1.    2.   3. 


(6,6)  (0,5)  (0,0)
(5,0)  (7,7)  (5,5)
(0,0)  (5,5)  (8,8)

https://www.jstor.org/stable/2951778
My question is how to find the values in figure 2?
path-value to find 

Can you add what you’ve tried thus far? Normally it helps to see where someone got stuck, and it helps to give a proper explanation said part.
